# How to add a legend category that doesn't exit in the data by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
doctor <- c("Dave", "Dave", "Sam", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Sam")
screened <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(doctor,screened)
df
```

And I plot the data by using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=doctor, fill=factor(screened))) +
  geom_bar(width=0.4) +
  geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..), vjust=-0.3) + 
  xlab("Doctor") +
  ylab("Screening Times") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

As you can see the legend only have the category of "1". How to add a category of "0" even it doesn't exit in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set the `limits` via `scale_fill_discrete`:

```r
doctor <- c("Dave", "Dave", "Sam", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Sam")
screened <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(doctor,screened)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=doctor, fill=factor(screened))) +
  geom_bar(width=0.4) +
  geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..), vjust=-0.3) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = factor(c(0, 1))) +
  xlab("Doctor") +
  ylab("Screening Times") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]